# Multiple word suggest based on matching documents on the first word

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 4.6 and I'm trying to make solr give me autocomplete suggestions based on multiple words. I've achieved this using spellcheck.collate, but the problem I'm facing now is that it returns suggestions that are not relevant to the search (the search is based on cars)

```
Example: Searching for something like "audi fo" will return audi + all the matching
items that have "fo" in them, something like audi ford, audi focus and so on.
```

Each document has multiple fields (make, model, bodycolour, etc). What I'm trying to achieve is to make solr return only the suggestions for the second word that match fields in the matched documents based on the first word.

I guess that I can write a custom component in Java using the Solr libraries and plug it, but I'm guessing there must be an easier way to achieve this using what Solr already knows.

Note: I've been studying the Solr documentation for a couple of days and this is the best I could find so far.

**solr.config**

```
<searchComponent name="com_test" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
 <lst name="spellchecker">
   <str name="name">com_test</str>
   <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
   <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.FSTLookup</str>
   <str name="field">com_test</str>
   <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
 </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/com_test">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">com_test</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>com_test</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

**schema.xml**

```
<field name="com_test" type="com_test" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<fieldType name="com_test" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant schema.xml and solrconfig.xml

Comment: The thing is that the autocomplete works fine for the second word if it finds a match on the first one. The problem is that the collate joins words that aren't from the same document. And I haven't found anything to get a proper match for the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

existing solr suggester is pretty basic when speaking about the data sources and configuration. It is up to you to craft corresponding source, whether using a field or a custom dictionary.
if you want the suggester to be able to produce the proper phrases, the best way is to index those phrases/word tuples together.

Comment: In the end I have concatenated the fields I am interesting in (prior to sending them to Solr) and just make the suggest based on the concatenation. So is there no other way to achieve this other than concatenation or custom components?

Comment: I'll mark it as an answer, because in the end we concatenated the fields together to get those suggestions. So, yeah...

Comment: Anyway you have to concatenate, either before SOLR, or develop your own source for suggester. FST based Suggester (the one you used above) builds a model by pulling those values from repository. So if you are not going to develop your own repository abstraction - yes, it's better to do what you have already done.